# Rails 4.1 assets pipeline, how to the load javascript at the bottom of the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have my css files in app/assets/stylesheets and javascript files in app/assets/javascript
(It seems like the vendor/assets and lib/assets folders are not working).

How do I tell the asset pipeline to render a javascript file at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you put a javascript file in your app/assets, it is automatically included on all your pages.

Answer (score 2):

If you by "render a javascript file" mean rendering the `<script src="youjavascriptfile.js"></script>` at the bottom, you could have something like this at the bottom of your layout:

```
    <%= yield(:javascript) %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then in your view you would put content into that like so:

```
<%= content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="youjavascriptfile.js"></script>
<% end %>
```

For more info, see the [Rails Guides on yield](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).